# Only scrape paragraphs containing certain words

Tags: python, web-scraping, nlp

I'm developing some code to scrape text from websites. I'm not interested to scrape the entire page, but just in sections of the page that contain certain words. Ideally, I want to scrape the entire paragraph that contains the word. I've seen examples that use the .find_all("p") line, however I found that many websites do not use HTML-defined paragraphs ("p"). Therefore I would like to refrain from that.

Right now, I'm using an approach were the text before and after a certain word is searched. However, the problem here is that the same sentences can be mentioned multiple times over. For example in the code below, the sentence "Drought is pushing food prices up sharply in East Africa" is mentioned 3 times. Here is the code:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = "https://www.un.org/africarenewal/news/drought-pushing-food-prices-sharply-east-africa"
req = Request(url, headers={"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0'})
page = urlopen(req, timeout = 5) # Open page within 5 seconds. This line skips 'empty' websites
htmlParse = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), 'lxml') #html5lib
SearchWords = ["drought", "water", "food"] # text must contain these words

textP = ""
text = ""
for word in SearchWords:
    print(word)
    for r in re.findall(re.compile('.{0,100}'+word+'.{0,100}'), htmlParse.text):
        textP = textP + r  

text= text + textP
print(text)
```

As mentioned, I would ideally get all the paragraphs that contain a certain word, without duplicates. Has anyone any experience with this? Much much appreciated!

Comment: How do you define a paragraph here? Your regex only matches any zero to 100 chars other than line break chars before `word` and after.

Comment: Correct; the code I've written now does not look for paragraphs, but just for characters before and after the word. So I would like to change that. Paragraphs I would define as some text seperated by a blankline. However I do not know how to approach that.

Comment: Do you have an example page where the content you want is not organised in paragraphs? You can use a set() at the end to remove duplicates btw.

Comment: Does my answer help?

Comment: @QHarr I was hoping to use this method on PDFs, such as https://recpnet.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Water_Stewardship.pdf. However, I first need to figure out how to properly extract text from such PDFs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To split a string into paragraphs, you can use a Python `re` with

```py
re.split(r'(?:\r\n?|\n){2,}', htmlParse.text)
```

Next, you want to get unique paragraphs containing one of the predefined strings:

```py
pars = set([p for p in re.split(r'(?:\r\n?|\n){2,}', htmlParse.text) if any(x in p for x in SearchWords)])
```

Now, if you want to perform a whole word case insensitive search, you can again use `re`:

```py
pars = set([p for p in re.split(r'(?:\r\n?|\n){2,}', htmlParse.text) if re.search(rf'\b(?:{"|".join(SearchWords)})\b', p, re.I)])
```

Here, `\b(?:drought|water|food)\b` regex will look for `drought`, `water` or `food` as whole words and `re.I` will ensure case insensitive search.

Comment: Great this is exactly what I was looking for! I now would like to apply this code also to scrape PDFs, however I'll first give it a go + will probably open up another question (if needed).

Comment: Great, consider dropping a comment if you have a problem with this solution here, below this answer.